# How can I change the array to be filled from user input?

Tags: arrays, pointers, user-input

This code works for what i am trying to do, but I need the string to be put in by the user. How can I change the array to be user based?

```
int main ()
{
    char str[] ="- This, a sample string."; 
    char * pch;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str," ,.-");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't put question in the title..give a meaningful title and put the question where it is meant to be. Also format the code using `{}` button available while posting question. Finally we need to know which language the code is written so use the tag appropriately.

Comment: Could you please edit to correct format. you can select the code and use `{}` button to get your code shown formatted

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ you can use [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) to take such input from a user.